# Deploy Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, deployment, entity-framework-4

i the last few days i struggle to solve this issue, i am trying to deploy asp.net site to production environment for the first time.

my asp.net web application is developed with Visual Studio 12, using .net 4, on my local machine (Windows 7) with sql server 2008 r2 database engine, in addition i am using Entity Framework as data provider.

in my production enviroment, that run on Windows Server 2003 Sp2, with IIS 6 and SQL Server 2008 r2 database engine, install .net 4 framework.

i dont have any visual studio, for debugin of configuration.

In the first time that the application trying to access the i am getting the error:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for  details.","StackTrace":"   at 
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand,  CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at 
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context,  ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)\r\n   at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\u003cT\u003e.GetEnumerator()
>   \r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)\r\n   at 
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
>   Dl.GetAllCategories() in 
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\likeaboss.co.il\App_Code\DL.cs:line 495\r\n
>   at BO.GetAllCategories() in 
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\likeaboss.co.il\App_Code\BO.cs:line 328\r\n
>   at  BO.GetAllCategoriesJobsJSON() in
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\likeaboss.co.il\App_Code\BO.cs:line 334\r\n
>   at JobManage.LoadCategory() in
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\likeaboss.co.il\JobManage.aspx.cs:line 
>   41","ExceptionType":"System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException"

(the error is send to client, after ajax call to server)

The connection to EF line is passed.

After i google my problem its seems to mean that EF is not update to the Windows Server data base.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: have you checked the inner exception for details as suggested

Answer (score 0):

The culprit could that a table/column that you had deleted from the database but not from your Entity diagram in the project. Right click your .EDMX file and click validate, you might get some helpful clues.